# Append "handout" option to white-out answer environments

Tags: beamer, color

I cannot seem to find a solution for a simple problem.

I would like for my slide handouts to white out the text in Answer blocks for printing. (Though this possibly allows students to highlight 
the white text and reveal it --- I welcome better answers.)

My hacked solutions do not white out things like lists.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=pst,dvips,10pt,handout]{beamer}

\theoremstyle{example}
\newtheorem*{question}{Question}
\newtheorem*{answer}{Answer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{MWE}
\begin{question}
When is $2+2 = 5$?
\end{question}
\pause
\begin{answer}
For extremely large values of 2.

Note:
\begin{enumerate}
\item Complaints about instructor should be directed to department chair.
\end{enumerate}
\end{answer}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: \color{white} works, but you need to do it again for enumerate.  To turn the green letters white, I'd have to dig into the interstices of beamer to find the name of the color being used.

Comment: Is there any way to automate the addition of "\color{white}" to the answers?

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the chapter about handouts in the beamer manual. You can define handout aware overlays. This way the answer is completely removed from the handout and not just colored white.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=pst,dvips,handout,10pt]{beamer}

\theoremstyle{example}
\newtheorem*{question}{Question}
\newtheorem*{answer}{Answer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{MWE}
\onslide<1-2| handout:1>
\begin{question}
When is $2+2 = 5$?
\end{question}

\onslide<2| handout:0>
\begin{answer}
For extremely large values of 2.

Note:
\begin{enumerate}
\item Complaints about instructor should be directed to department chair.
\end{enumerate}
\end{answer}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---

**Edit:**

Of course you can also automate this behavior. You can use for example the `etoolbox` to do so. But be aware, that there are situations this does not work as intended, as the answer environment will always be shown on the second slide.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{answer}{\onslide<2|handout:0>}
\AfterEndEnvironment{answer}{\onslide<handout:1>}
```

Comment: Cool.  But I was hoping, since I only want to overlay the answer environment, that this could be automated somehow?

Comment: @vrbatim See my edit.